# Proof that $e^{i\theta}/e^ {i\phi} = e^{i(\theta - \phi)}$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, eulerian-numbers

Could anyone please help me with proving that

\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\phi}}= e^{i(\theta-\phi)}
\end{equation}

Is $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ useful in this proof?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Refer to the quotient rule of exponents: $a^x/a^y=a^{x-y}$

Comment: @Luthier It is not obvious that the quotient rule for exponents is valid for complex numbers. It would need a little more explanation to be a full solution.

Comment: They are still subjected to the quotient rule, so $a^{ix}/a^{iy}=a^{ix-iy}=a^{i(x-y)}$

Comment: @Luthier As Arthur said, this need more explanation since exponents rules are not always valid for complex numbers

Comment: Interesting, can someone add an answer?

Comment: This follows from $e^{i\theta’}e^{i\phi} = e^{i(\theta’ + \phi)}$ where $\theta’$ could be $\theta - \phi$. Doing the multiplication should be marginally simpler than doing division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rationalise the denominator with the complex conjugate of $e^{i\phi}$ which will then give you:
$$\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\phi}}=\frac{\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)}{\left(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi\right)\left(\cos\phi-i\sin\phi\right)}\\
=\frac{\left(\cos\theta\cos\phi+\sin\theta\sin\phi\right)+i\left(\sin\theta\cos\phi-\cos\theta\sin\phi\right)}{\cos^2\phi-i^2\sin^2\phi}\\
=e^{i\left(\theta-\phi\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I didn't know how to solve the second to last step, even now I am a bit confused just by looking at it. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @MathNoob I just substituted the formula of $\cos\left(\theta-\phi\right)$ and $\sin\left(\theta-\phi\right)$ and the denominator becomes $\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi=1$

Comment: I didn't know that formula, now it all makes sense. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:
The identity you provide is useful, the other key idea is :

$$\frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac{a+b}{c+d} \frac{c-d}{c-d} = \frac{(a+b)(c-d)}{c^2-d^2} $$

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly how I tried to solve this problem but I got stuck at the end.